# How to get the normal username as a variable

Tags: shell-script, shell, make

I'm trying to create a makefile script and I tried to automatically create multiple folders in a specific directory. However, I've had issues when trying to implement this:
First, I tried doing it the normal route:

```bsh
mkdir ~/Documents/testfolder
```

However, it gave me this error:
`mkdir: cannot create directory '/root/Documents/testfolder': No such file or directory`

I then tried using the `$USER` variable with this command:

```bsh
mkdir /home/$USER/Documents/testfolder
```

but then it'll be registered as `/home/root/Documents/...` and cause an error. Makefile scripts require to be ran as sudo most of the time so it's pretty problematic for me. Any help?

Comment: Welcome, it seems that you are running the commands logged as  `root`. It's not adviceable to do that. Use `sudo` to perform super user tasks, logged in as your user.

Comment: “Makefile scripts require to be ran as sudo most of the time” — they shouldn’t... And if you’re writing your own Makefile, and you want it to create directories in your home directory, run it as your regular user, not `root` or with `sudo`.

Comment: Makefiles generally should **not** require root. "Make install" is the only acceptable exception.

Comment: /root/Documents has to exist, or use 'mkdir -p'

Comment: If you *must* run your makefile using sudo then perhaps what you are looking for is `$SUDO_USER`?

Answer (score 1):

If your shell environment has a `$USER`, things should work, since `make` imports all environment variables. But you need to take care whether `$USER` really reflects the current user id.

Inside Makefiles, there are however other other rules than inside shell scripts. You could check this with the following makefile:

```
all:
        echo USER: $(USER)
```

and this should work. Note that `make` needs $(...) for make macro names that are longer than a single character. The brackets are needed because otherwise, `$U` would be expanded.

Now to your permission problem. It seems that you did use a program like `su` or `sudo` that changes the user id wihtout changing the shell variable `$USER`.

Try to directly login as the user you like to run `make`.